# How to find all strings of non-negative even numbers and odd number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to find all strings of a non-negative even number of a's followed by an odd number of b's: aab, aaaabbb, aabbb...

```
[w for w in words.words() if re.search('(aa|bb)$',w)][:5]
```

really stuck any hints that I can use?

Comment: Please add test case for it.

Comment: What would a negative number of a's look like?

Answer (score 2):

Even is `2n` and Odds `2n+1` so you can implement it like this:
`\b(aa)*b(bb)*\b`

[Check This](https://regex101.com/r/wY3mE0/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about you search for all `a+b+` substrings and then filter them out checking how much `a`s and `b`s are there in the match:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "ab, aab, abb, aaaabbb, aabbb, test, ab, aabb"
>>> [item for item, a, b in re.findall(r'((a+)(b+))', s) 
     if len(a) % 2 == 0 and len(b) % 2 != 0]
['aab', 'aaaabbb', 'aabbb']
```